# Generate React/NextJS dynamic components and bind events from static HTML

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have an API, which returns `Json` with `HTML` string like:

```
{
   content: '<div><button class="some-class-name">Click me</button></div>'
}
```

- `class`, but not `className`, but this is not the problem now.

I know that, I can render that HTML (NextJS):

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: response.content }} />
```

The problem is the button, that has an event `onClick`.

Is there a way or a package, which I can use for that - create components from a static HTML and bind events ?

1 possible way that I guess may works is to read the `HTML` string extract the elements like (`div`, `button`) and create components from scratch.

Comment: Thanks, it is one possible solution, but it adds the event to the root element `const el = e.target.closest("B");` , but the second answer is what I am searching, I think.

Comment: yes, u can add it as answer if you want :)

Comment: Do you see a button that says mark as duplicate?